# Sort on discriminator - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model where I am using a discriminator.
As I cannot share the original code, here is a mockup

```
public class Dog {}

public class SomeDog : Dog {}
```

Now I want my entities to be sorted by the `Discriminator`, having `SomeDog` first and only after these, having my `Dog` entities.

Is there any way to actually sort on my `Discriminator`? Or do I have to find a workaround?

Comment: Possible way I can think of would be to get hierarchy tree and count number of nodes so you can use these values for sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried sort when you read list of context?

Example:

```
YourContext.Dogs.OrderBy(d => (d is SomeDog) ? 1 : 2)
```

Comment: Is it supported by the LINQ Provider? (too lazy to try)